# How to make html table cells in square shape?

Tags: html

I want to create alphabet chart. I am facing a problem with shape of html table cells. I want to get html table cells in square shape like below the image.

[https://uolsargodha.files.wordpress.com/2013/10/chess_board-svg.png][1]

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Please insert your code.

Comment: I inserted my code

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS properties `width` and `height` to set the height and width of the table cells.

```css
td {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
      <td>top left</td>
      <td>top right</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>bottom left</td>
      <td>bottom right</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It doesn't work properly

Comment: @KunalTiwalkar Please see: [What Do You Mean “It Doesn't Work”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616). Please edit your question to include the attempts you have tried and the problem you have with these attempts.

Comment: Because i am using bootstrap 3

Comment: @KunalTiwalkar Please edit your question to include the fact that you are using bootstrap 3. Also add the attempts you have tried to create the squares cells and describe in detail the result you get and the problems you have. "Does not work" is not a helpful description for solving the problem. When you test the solutions by pressing "Run code snippet" in these answers you will see that you get square cells, so the issue must be something else.

Comment: @KunalTiwalkar Keep in mind that you might have other CSS rules which might change the CSS properties for the `<td>` elements. You might need to change the CSS selector to be more specific than the other CSS selectors which are already on your site. The selector `td { ... }` as seen in the answer is very basic and can be "overwritten" by more complex CSS selectors.

Answer (score 0):

```css
table td,table th {
width:150px;
height:150px;
display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: It doesn't work properly